# React Native Background Video Not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have copied and referenced all the starter files for using a video as my background in react native yet it still doesn't show up. I'm not getting any errors. I've referenced the documentation and have been stuck on this for 2 hours.

Here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from "react-
native";

import Video from "react-native-video";
import LightVideo from "./Turntablevid.mp4";

  export default class BackgroundVid extends Component {
    render() {
     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Video repeat source={LightVideo} resizeMode="cover" style=
        {StyleSheet.absoluteFill} />
      <View>
       <Text style={styles.header}>Login</Text>
       <TextInput
        placeholder="Email"
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Password"
        secureTextEntry
        style={styles.input}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
  );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 alignItems: "center",
 justifyContent: "center",
  },
 header: {
 fontSize: 30,
 color: "#FFF",
 backgroundColor: "transparent",
 textAlign: "center"
  },
  input: {
  width: 300,
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: "#FFF",
  marginVertical: 15,
  paddingLeft: 15
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Example:

```
<Video source={require('./Turntablevid.mp4')}
       ref={(ref) => {
         this.player = ref
       }}                                      // Store reference
       rate={1.0}                              // 0 is paused, 1 is normal.
       volume={1.0}                            // 0 is muted, 1 is normal.
       muted={false}                           // Mutes the audio entirely.
       paused={false}                          // Pauses playback entirely.
       resizeMode="cover"                      // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.*
       repeat={true}                           // Repeat forever.
       playInBackground={false}                // Audio continues to play when app entering background.
       playWhenInactive={false}                // [iOS] Video continues to play when control or notification center are shown.
       ignoreSilentSwitch={"ignore"}           // [iOS] ignore | obey - When 'ignore', audio will still play with the iOS hard silent switch set to silent. When 'obey', audio will toggle with the switch. When not specified, will inherit audio settings as usual.
       progressUpdateInterval={250.0}          // [iOS] Interval to fire onProgress (default to ~250ms)
       onLoadStart={this.loadStart}            // Callback when video starts to load
       onLoad={this.setDuration}               // Callback when video loads
       onProgress={this.setTime}               // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
       onEnd={this.onEnd}                      // Callback when playback finishes
       onError={this.videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
       onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
       onTimedMetadata={this.onTimedMetadata}  // Callback when the stream receive some metadata
       style={styles.backgroundVideo} />

// Later to trigger fullscreen
this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer()

// To set video position in seconds (seek)
this.player.seek(0)

// Later on in your styles..
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundVideo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Appstate for stopping Background Video....

this [example](https://reactnativecode.com/detect-app-is-in-background/) will help to detect Background state of application.

then you can put your method into that state into this condition:

```
if nextAppstate === 'background' then setstate your Pausemethod()
```